# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream-stream join without equality predicate is not supported;

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

While running sample streaming join query getting the **org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream-stream join without equality predicate is not supported;**

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemoryStream
implicit val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

val input1 = MemoryStream[Int]
val input2 = MemoryStream[Int]

val df1 = input1.toDF.select($"value" as "leftKey", ($"value" * 2) as "leftValue")
val df2 = input2.toDF.select($"value" as "rightKey", ($"value" * 3) as "rightValue")

val joined = df1.join(df2, expr("leftKey < rightKey"))
val q = joined.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("test").start()
input1.addData(1)
q.awaitTermination(10000)
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream-stream join without equality predicate is not supported;;
Join Inner, (leftKey#5 < rightKey#10)
:- Project [value#42 AS leftKey#5, (value#42 * 2) AS leftValue#6]
:  +- Streaming RelationV2 MemoryStreamDataSource$[value#42]
+- LocalRelation <empty>, [rightKey#10, rightValue#11]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$StreamingJoinStrategy$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$4.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$4.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Answer (score 1):

For streaming join conditions non-equai joins are not supported. We need to change it to equai join.

```
val joined = df1.join(df2, expr("leftKey = rightKey"))
```

**Code**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemoryStream
implicit val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

val input1 = MemoryStream[Int]
val input2 = MemoryStream[Int]

val df1 = input1.toDF.select($"value" as "leftKey", ($"value" * 2) as "leftValue")
val df2 = input2.toDF.select($"value" as "rightKey", ($"value" * 3) as "rightValue")

val joined = df1.join(df2, expr("leftKey = rightKey"))
val q = joined.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("test").start()
input1.addData(1)
q.awaitTermination(10000)
```